# How can "Enter a correctly formatted URL" in chrome's DNS setting?

Tags: dns, chrome

I want to set `223.5.5.5` as my DNS server in chrome.

[image]

It says `Enter a correctly formatted URL`,what is the correct format for `223.5.5.5` then?

Comment: `Secure DNS` is not the same as traditional/ordinary DNS.

Comment: @jsotola very easy to miss

Answer (score 1):

Chrome requires a DoH (DNS over HTTPS) endpoint here. For example, for Cloudflare resolver this would be

```
https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query
```